# Is it possible to disable scrolling on an outside element and maintain scrolling on inner element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter BS version 2.1.  Basically I have a Modal that will have 2 divs side by side. Assume div1 has a height of 700px, I want to limit the outer div to 400px. Div2's max height will be the outer div's height.

Unfortunately what's happening is the outer div is getting the scrolling, and the inner div gets a scrollbar that can only scroll about 10px. I've tried overflow:hidden on the outer div, but no luck.

This is what it looks like right now: http://jsfiddle.net/sLqkdbr3/3/ . Your help would be appreciated, thanks!

This is my html because I'm forced to paste it:

```
<body>
    <div class='show_location_picker'>Click to Show</div>
    <div class="modal hide fade" id='locationModal'>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h3>Select Location</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row span10">Enter your address
                <input type='address' />
            </div>
            <div class="row center" style='overflow: hidden'>
                <div class="span3" style='overflow: scroll'>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                    <p>Store 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span5">
                    <div id="map_canvas" data-lat='44.616698' data-long='-69.416702'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it, you have to make little changes in the css, first of all change the modal body overflow visible:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

and give inner div some height and overflow to scroll:

```
.span3 {
    max-height: 400px;
    width: 220px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

I have currently added the css to the classes applied on the both div. you can adjust them instead of modifying the bootstrap original css.

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/sLqkdbr3/7/